# Why 'modality', when 'mode' already existed?

Tags: etymology

[mode](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=mode) precedes [modality](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=modality). 
I cannot discern any difference in their modern meanings: so what caused 'modality' 's lexicalization, when 'mode' already existed?

[OED on 'mode':](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/120575#eid36509316)

> 4. a. A way or manner in which something is done or takes place; a method of proceeding in any activity, business, etc. Freq. with *of*.   [...]
> 5. a. A particular form, manner, or variety in which some quality, phenomenon, or condition occurs or is manifested.   [...]
>
> II. In senses derived from French.
>
> 7. a. A prevailing fashion, custom, practice, or style, esp. one characteristic of a particular place or period.

[OED on 'modality'](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/120571?redirectedFrom=modality#eid):

> 1. a. Those aspects of a thing which relate to its mode, or manner or state of being, as distinct from its substance or identity; the non-essential aspect or attributes of a concept or entity. Also: a particular quality or attribute denoting the mode or manner of being of something. Cf. [mode n. 6a.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/120575#eid36509316)

Comment: Cross posted [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/94640/mode-vs-modality) - worth checking there before answering.

Comment: I think this is the second time I've had to remind you on EL&U that [cross-posting is inappropriate on StackExchange](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5302/55623). This wouldn't be so disappointing if it weren't for the fact that you yourself asked that meta-question and got an answer a long time ago. Please abide by the rules and norms of the site.

Comment: @JoshFriedlander The question above and that on ELL differ.

Comment: @DanBron The question above and that on ELL differ. Also, the answer on https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4684/50720 differs?

Comment: @Canada-Area51Proposal And the very same question on [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/22752/5609)? And on site policy, Meta.se governs. The rule is so not cross-post. Don't do it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

They're different words. A mode is a state something can have; it may have several modes. The attribute of modality means that it has modes, as opposed to not having them, or having only one. (Compare stateful and stateless in programming - some applications are capable of having different states, while some are not.)

In practice, I often see the word modality being used in place of mode. In time it may come to be synonymous.